# Speed up insert into questdb using influxDBLine protocol

Tags: database, insert, questdb

I'm doing a project related to storing live trading data.
Currently, we are using questDB and insert to it using influxdb line protocol(TCP).
Here is the link https://questdb.io/docs/reference/api/ilp/overview.
However, the rate of packets dropped is about 5% and, I want it to be less than 1%.
A packet is likely to be dropped when the number of packets received per minute is more than 2 million.
Are there any way to speed up the insert speed or any other time series database I can try?

Comment: How many TCP connections do you use? The same question of the number of tables you write to. Have you tried configuring the worker pools?
https://questdb.io/docs/reference/api/ilp/tcp-receiver#capacity-planning

Comment: Currently I only using 1 tcp connection, so how many threads for writer should I use? By default, the number of threads for writing to database is 1 , am I right?

Comment: Then you should set `line.tcp.io.worker.count` and `line.tcp.writer.worker.count` to 1. How many cores do you have on that machine?